# clearcase installation on solaris 10 globalzone

Tags: vmware, clearcase, virtualization, solaris-10

We are in the process of migrating to a new DataCenter and the company involved in helping us to do this is suggesting we use virtualization and install ClearCase on one of these virtual env's. My experience with Virtualization is at the minimum and I am trying to read through the documentation provided by Rational in this case.

if someone has already been working with Global zones and non-global zone's, could you explain it to me the right way of configuring this without losing any performace. As per the documents, we would like to install ClearCase on the global zone and not install it on non-global zone as there is no real benefit or a performance gain, rather more administrative overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my past installations on Solaris, you *have* to:

- install it on global zone (for the mvfs part to install properly and be available for all the ngz)
- install it on the non-global zones you need ClearCase

ClearCase won't be able to access all the paths it needs during the installation in an ngz, hence the first install on global zone.

See, for instance for CC8.0: "[Installing Rational ClearCase to support non-global zones.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.platforms.doc/topics/t_ux_sun5_sol10_ngz_install.htm)"

> Install and configure Rational ClearCase on the global zone before you install and configure it on any non-global zones.
>   If you plan to run dynamic views on a non-global zone, the MVFS must be installed on the global zone on that computer. Specifically, this means that you cannot choose the ClearCase Server-only Installation option when installing Rational ClearCase on the global zone.

I never experienced a lack of performance because of being in an ngz, provided you reserve the appropriate quantity of resource (disk, memory) to each ngz.

I never used ClearCase in a global zone only, since I needed to start/stop ClearCase in each ngz independently. Hence my requirement for having CC in ngz, not just in global zone.

Comment: Thanks Vonc. My requirement is not to have more than one ngz. In that case, we are wondering if we even need a ngz. Why have the overhead of installing ClearCase on Global Zone and then again on non global zone. What are your thoughts? Do you see any harm in terms of performance if we just use ClearCase on Global Zone?

Comment: @soothsayer if you need to have ClearCase in a ngz (even just one), then you *need* ClearCase in the global zone. But having ClearCase in the global zone *only* would mean not all its feature would be available from a ngz. In my case, installing in both was not an overhead. It was a requirement for having a fully functional ClearCase (on Solaris 10).

Comment: do you know exactly what components are installed on the Global Zone and what components of ClearCase are installed on Non Global Zone? So is the View Server and Vob Server installed on Global Zone and then again on Non Global Zone?

Comment: @soothsayer the global zone installation is a full one. The ngz one is a partial one, since it cannot install mvfs component (dynamic view) and relies on the global zone for that feature. However, each ngz installation can have its own Vob and view server.